# Getting exception while pressing a button in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a button  using c#  to browse files and folders from windows. My sample code is given below. The problem is: when I click on the browse button I am getting the following exception in the line I have marked in the comment in the following code:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException'   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

My sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        Size = new Size(400, 380);
        Button browse = new Button();
        browse.Parent = this;
        browse.Text = "Browse";
        browse.Location = new Point(220, 52);
        browse.Size = new Size(6 * Font.Height, 2 * Font.Height);
        browse.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonbrowseOnClick);
    }

    public void ButtonbrowseOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         int size = -1;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();  
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();  //getting exception in this line
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            try
            {
                string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                size = text.Length;
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(size); 
        Console.WriteLine(result);   
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Is there anything  wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[STAThread]` attribute at top of your `Main` method, should solves the problem.

```
[STAThread]          //   <--------Add this
public static void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is there any way to print the  location of the selected file? @Hossein Narimani Rad

Comment: Is there any way to print the location of the selected file? @Hossein Narimani Rad

Comment: You have already done it your self. To get the location of the selected file, you can use `openFileDialog1.FileName`

Comment: @user5379550 In Windows Forms you may try `MessageBox.Show`

Comment: if I want to use the value of 'file' variable in another function (say: ButtonbrowseOnClick2(object sender, EventArgs e) ) How will I do that? normally this function will not recognize the file variable. @Hossein Narimani Rad

Comment: @user5379550 you may define a string variable (field or property) in your form class and set it to the value of `FileName` in your first method, then in your second method also you can call it.